# Find index of conditional selection Python numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an numpy array with numbers from 0 to 2:

```
myArray = np.random.randint(3, size=(255,255,1)).astype('uint8')
```

now i want all indexes where it has value 0.

for example `(220,15)`

so that i can do 
`myArray[220][15]` and retrieve 0.

Comment: What did you already try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your array has three dimensions, even if the third can only take `0` as its index, so your indices will have three values.

You can use numpy's n dimensional enumerator to iterate through the array, getting a list of indices where the value is 0.

```
zero_indices = [index for index, value in np.ndenumerate(myArray) if value == 0]
```

Edit: Slam's answer should be a lot faster though.

Comment: @QuestionableQuestions Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You need [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) without elements, and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) `em for your preferred format:

```
>>> indices = np.where(myArray == 0)
>>> element_wise = zip(*indices)
>>> next(element_wise)
(0, 3, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for this valid answer, the one below fits my needs a little better though.

Comment: No problem, please mark suitable answer as accepted to let other people know this is solved issue.